Episode where a family is trapped inside a house
I remember seeing this episode when I was a child, around 1985, and at that time, it was the scariest thing I had ever seen.
Here is the plot (or at least what I remember of it, so this may not be 100% accurate): one morning, a family wakes up. They soon realize that they are trapped inside the house. Something is preventing them from opening the main door, I believe it was some kind of metallic wall outside the whole house. The father somehow tries to dig under the door (maybe through the floor ?), then realizes that the barrier is also under the house. I remember that the temperature rises toward the end of the episode, while something is slowing filling the fireplace..

Do you know if the whole series was about this family or could this have been a multipart episode of say The Twilight Zone?

I think it was just one episode with these characters, but honestly I could be wrong. I know that the explanation was given in the last minute or two, but can't remember it.

Sounds like the episode Child's Play in the 1984 anthology series Hammer House of Mystery and Suspense:

A family awakens to find themselves trapped in their own home, all windows and doors sealed by impenetrable walls. Now they are faced with a bitter sequence of paranormal events forces that have taken over their lives.

They discover a solid metal barrier, the house gets hotter and hotter and some green slime oozes from the fireplace near the end. The twist?

This all took place in some girl's dollhouse in the future.

The entire thing is available on Youtube.

Thank you so much, this is it. As MrLore commented, it sounded much like an episode of The Twilight Zone, and I actually searched the whole list of episodes and couldn't find it.

Reading the list of episodes, I realize that I had also been looking for several of those stories for some time..

I now found a Youtube link for Child's Play in English and put it instead of the Spanish one. You can find at least one more episode there ('In Possession') if you search for 'hammer house suspense'.

The original chapter is from The a Twilight Zone, and the name of the chapter is "Five characters in search of an exit" Season 3 episodio 14... 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Characters_in_Search_of_an_Exit

What makes you think that this is a right answer? Please add explanation to your answer else it is likely to be removed. Also there is already an answer marked as right.
