Looking for an old movie about family trapped / blocked in the house
It's a color movie, presumably American filmed in presumably 70-80 th.
Plot as I remember it:
Usual family wakes up one morning and finds that they're blocked in their house, there is some kind of unbreakable wall they can't pass through. Father and mother trying different ways to get out (I remember they tried to explode the wall in garage, but with no success) and looking for explanation on what happened. Their kid (I don't remember boy or girl or they had 2 kids) behaves strange and always is somehow connected to mysterious sign (I don't clearly remember this sign, I believe it's blue octopus), which is shown on box of matches and TV. 

Similar question here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21179/episode-where-a-family-is-trapped-inside-a-house

Also here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68267/19561

Child's Play

"A family awakens to find themselves trapped in their own home, all
  windows and doors sealed by impenetrable walls. Now they are faced
  with a bitter sequence of paranormal events forces that have taken
  over their lives."

You can watch it here (big twist at the end):



0:26:25 : They are trying to break through the wall. 

Yes, this one! Thanks alot, I was unsure it was named Child's play, because this name led me to Chucky movie! And didn't know it's a part of some series.
